# How bitwise shift operators are used to combine bytes into a larger integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

The following code combines two bytes into one 16 bit integer.

```
unsigned char byteOne = 0b00000010; // 2
unsigned char byteTwo = 0b00000011; // 3

uint16_t i = 0b0000000000000000;
i = (byteOne << 8) | byteTwo; //515
```

I'm trying to understand WHY this code works.

If we break this down and just focus on one byte, `byteOne`; This is an 8 bit value equal to 00000010. So, left-shifting this by 8 bits should always yield `00000000` (as the bits shifted off the end are lost), right? This seems to be the case with the following code:

```
uint8_t i = (byteOne << 8); // equal to 0, always, no matter what 8 bit value is assigned to byteOne
```

But if this way of thinking was correct, then

```
uint16_t i = (byteOne << 8) | byteTwo;
```

Should be equivalent to

```
uint16_t i = 0 | byteTwo; // Because 0b00000010 << 8 == 0b00000000
```

Or just

```
uint16_t i = byteTwo; // Because 0b00000000 | 0b00000011 == 0b00000011
```

But they're not equivalent and this is throwing me off. Is `byteOne` being cast/converted into a 16 bit int before the shifting operation? That would explain what's going on here as then

```
0b0000000000000010 << 8 == 0b0000001000000000 // 512
```

If `byteOne` isn't being converted into a 16 bit int before the shifting operation, then please explain why the `(byteOne << 8)` isn't evaluating to 0 when assigning to a 16 bit integer.

Comment: [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to `int` from small types.

Comment: Have you tried `auto i = (byteOne << 8);` and seen what type the compiler chooses to give `i` (hence is the type of the expression `byteOne << 8`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes--when you do almost any sort of operation on any value smaller than an `int`  the first thing that happens is that the value is promoted to `int` (or, in some cases, `unsigned int`).

In case you really care about the details that apply here (§[conv.prom]/1):

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion rank (6.8.4) is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned int`.

Then the operation happens on the promoted value (§[expr.shift]/1):

> The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.
> [...]
> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. So what happens with `uint8_t i = (byteOne << 8)`? Is it not promoted then because I'm assigning the value into an 8 bit type? And what if I had 8 bytes that I wanted to combine into a data type larger than int, like `uint64_t`, would the compiler know to convert each of the 8 bytes to 64 bit types before performing the shift operations?

Comment: In the first case, it gets promoted to int, then the result truncated back to `uint8_t`. When you're dealing with something larger than `int`, you generally want to convert the values to the correct type before you to the operation.

Answer (score 0):

As the shift does not hapen 'inplace' (`byteOne = byteOne << 8`), the compiler needs to use a register for the intermediate result.
In the line `i = (byteOne << 8) | byteTwo;` the size of the register for the intermediate is not specified (for example with a cast). Only the final result has to be `uint16_t`. So for the intermediate result it's up to the compiler.

When your code snipped is feed to a compiler you could get the following assembler code:

```
;// copy the two bytes and the word in the stack
movb    $2, -1(%rbp) ;// uint8_t byteOne = 2
movb    $3, -2(%rbp) ;// uint8_t byteTwo = 3
movw    $0, -4(%rbp) ;// uint16_t i = 0
;// move the byteOne into the acumulate register(32bit)
movzbl  -1(%rbp), %eax ;// uint32_t temp = byteOne
;// shift left by 8
sall    $8, %eax ;// temp = temp << 8
;// move temp to different register
movl    %eax, %edx ;// uint32_t temp2 = temp
;// move the byteTwo into the acumulate register(32bit)
movzbl  -2(%rbp), %eax ;// temp = byteTwo
;// logical or of temp2 and temp
orl     %edx, %eax ;// temp2 = temp2 | temp
;// copy back to stack location of i
movw    %ax, -4(%rbp) ;// i = (uint16_t)temp2
```

`%eax` is a 32-bit register, therefore no overflow. The cast to `uint16_t` is done actively by MOVWord `movw    %ax, -4(%rbp)`.

I'm not sure how the compiler desides which register size to use for these intermediate results, but I suspect that it depends on your system and compiler.

The compiler on my system `g++.exe (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.2.0` seams to use 32bit registers as standard.
The following code used 32 bit registers, too and therefore did not return the expected result:

```
unsigned char byteOne = 0b00000010; // 2
unsigned char byteTwo = 0b00000011; // 3
uint16_t i = 0b0000000000000000;
i = ((byteOne << 32) | byteTwo << 24) >> 24; // 3
```

The same 32 bit `%eax` register is used, therefore the overflow ocured.
So if the intermediate result is not exceeding 32 bit the result is as expected like with:

```
unsigned char byteOne = 0b00000010; // 2
unsigned char byteTwo = 0b00000011; // 3 
uint16_t i = 0b0000000000000000;
i = ((byteOne << 16) | byteTwo << 8) >> 8; // 515
```

The compiler for an 8bit Microcontroller will most certainly give a different result.

Comment: This seems to be more confirmation of the OP's result than an explanation of why that result is mandated by C++ / of why that C++ source resulted in this particular batch of assembly. (If C++ had called for a different result, different assembly would have been produced.)

Comment: Of course it confirms the OP's result, but it is an explanation. Did you read it completely? 
`i = (byteOne << 8) | byteTwo;` produces intermediate results with no specified bit width, so it's up to the compiler to choose the right registers from the available ones in the system.
C++ code is just text, there is no direct machine code representation, it's up to the compiler to interpret it.

Comment: I'm more into the hardware- and low level programming. Therefore I like explanations which express the cause of something more, than something like: C++ language allows integer promotion and it may be converted to int.

Comment: *"`i = (byteOne << 8) | byteTwo;` produces intermediate results with no specified bit width"* -- this is false. The bit width of the intermediate result is specified by the C++ standard to be the same as that of an `int`.

Comment: *"I like explanations which express the cause of something"* -- that's fine, but when you look at the machine instructions produced by a C++ compiler, you are looking at an effect, not a cause. The compiler produced those instructions because they produce the result called for by the C++ standard. For example: *"`%eax` is a 32-bit register, therefore no overflow"* neglects to consider that the compiler would have simulated an overflow if overflow was required by the standard. The cause is the C++ standard. The effect is that the machine instructions do not force an overflow.

Comment: Another way to look at the situation: By looking at the assembly, you can explain **how** the compiler accomplished the observed functionality, but you cannot explain **why** the compiler produced that assembly. The OP is trying to understand the "why".